# error in Chrome when displaying inline-block li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, css

I'm pretty new to web-coding and in my attempt to create jQuery based menu bars complete with dropdowns I have stumbled upon some vast differences between broswers. Below you can see that while FF and Safari are the same, IE is actually behaving and Opera is ok-ish, Chrome gets it totally wrong. As far as I can tell I have all the latest versions.

[image: what happens in different browsers]

I removed the code from here and pasted it in: (doesn't want to let me link properly) so: jsfiddle.net/2hCR2/

Just in case, support for older versions of IE (6-7) is not required.

Right now I'm mostly concerned with the positioning aspect. Any assistance is much appreciated!

****EDIT:** After continuing to play with the chrome developer tools I realized that when I manually set the 1st list (pants/t-shirt) to `display:block` it displays as expected (exactly like FF and Safari in the image) so it appears that this is more of a javascript/jQuery issue not updating the DOM correctly(?). I also noticed that when I put the code is JSFiddle and ran the script in Chrome it produced the same error, but when I ran JSFiddle in FF (exact same fiddle link) it renders correctly.

Comment: Is there JavaScript involved, too?

Comment: you have syntax error in js code, closing braces & semi-colon are missing. you might want to add that

Comment: true, its a snippet of code that goes on afterwards and i had neglected to close it when I copied part to this site

Comment: should the menu_dropdown and the submenu be visible at the same time?  In other words, when I hover over Categories, should I see what the other browsers do?  Or should I see Pants - T-shirt in a menu, and then see Jeans - Khakis when I hover over Pants?

Comment: eventually yes, it will appear as a hovered submenu independently, but right now I'm focusing on the positioning aspect of it, because there might be something I've done wrong or that requires changing. Once I have that sorted, then I can write the script to make it appear/disappear.

Comment: That's a Chrome bug. I've also experienced glitches with `.show(0)`. Changing it to `.show(1)` or `.show()` solves the issue for me on Chrome.

Comment: And for the record, it does not happen in Chrome Canary, so the glitch has been fixed.

Comment: interesting... well that is fixed, many thanks, I don't know how the point system works on the site, but if you want to type that up as an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as solved/answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not happen in Chrome Canary (version 24) but it does in stable (version 22). Apparently it is a bug which has been fixed.

You can either wait a month or two so that all Chrome users get the fix, or just use `.show()` instead of `.show(0)`.